# How to use a row value in a query to influence the selection of the query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Lets say I have a table `auth_token` with values `id_type` and `valid_to`. Depending on the `id_type` I want to fetch all tokens with a `valid_to` which are less than `time() - x`. So in this case `x` will have another value once `id_type` is `a` then once `id_type` is `b`.

So let's have an example: once `id_type = a` I want to have the same row to be selected once `valid_to = time() - 3600` and when `id_type = b` I want the same row to be selected once `valid_to = time()`.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Comment: Isn't it a simple where clause like 'Select * from auth_token where (id_type = 'a' and valid_to = time() - 3600) OR (id_type = 'b' and valid_to = time());

Comment: I guess that is the solution which is not as hard as I thought it would be. Thanks :)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case when condition in where clause.

```
i.e.

    Select * 
    from auth_token 
    where (CASE WHEN id_type = 'a' THEN valid_to = ? WHEN id_type = 'b' THEN valid_to = ? END);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as skelwa explained. Applying a where clause with `and` and `or` is enough for this case.

My example would unfold as the following query:

> Select * from auth_token where (id_type = 'a' and valid_to = time() - 3600) OR (id_type = 'b' and valid_to = time())